# How to make deleted items in "show view" invisible in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm creating a web development framework with Eclipse RCP.

I did not need the view I made, so I removed the code below and the icon image from plugin.xml.

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
        <view
            category="..."
            name="..."
            icon="..."
            class="..."
            id="..."
            >
    </extension>
```

By the way, I see the removed item in "show view". The icon shows a red square.

How do I remove it?

Comment: You may need to reset the perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the "Clear the configuration area before launching" checkbox in your launch configuration. `plugin.xml` contents are cached otherwise.

[image: Configuration tab of the launch configuration dialog]

Comment: I already have the "Clear the configuration area before launching" checkbox Enabled. Are there any other causes?

Comment: Like @greg-449 mentions, you might need to Reset the perspective. I'm not sure if view shortcuts get cleared this way.

Comment: I didn't solve it, but thanks for the reply.